# In mobile view how can i change side by side tabs to vertical tabs one by one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

1. Below link I tried in my code.
2. For side by side tabs https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs.
3. In web view ,Its working fine.
4. But here In mobile view ,I have to change as vertical tabs.

Comment: Please read through this before posting any more to SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

you have to go with responsive design website(RWD). In the mobile view, you can adjust the media screen. min-width and max width. Please check the below link:

https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-responsive-and-adaptive-design/